# Genymotion apps crash/freeze

Tags: android, genymotion

whenever i open any app using genymotion ( facebook, clash of clans, and google search ) they just close right away or sometimes i just get black screen and it freezes until i close the app down.

I tried using genymotion 2.2.2 and 1.3.1 with VM 4.2 and i also tried 4.3, i also tried using the current Virtual devices available + ARM translation 1.1.1 and gapps(android 4.3/4.2.2/4.1), and i tried old virtual devices that used to be available for 1.3 and it had Google apps included ( and i think ARM support ).

i dont think its related to genymotion at this point, any idea ?

processor : AMD phenom-2x2 with AMD-V enabled
OS : Windows 7 64x

Comment: Any app?  You cannot run *ANY* app on your Genymotion emulator?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike all the default apps like clock, talk and gallery works fine, also i tested twitter and it seems to be working fine.
however i tried facebook and the same happens.

Comment: not sure but maybe if you've got GoogleApps on board your genymotion device, you are missing google services. Which means, you should install it or update. The fastest way would be installing google maps and after you run (notification will pop up) from notification go direct to google services update market page. **But you must have to install first google aps before that step..

Comment: @Fareed Nagy Did you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question appears to ask why **no** applications run on Genymotion, it is in fact, just about **some** applications.

The most likely problem is that, as @deadfish points out, Genymotion does not include GoogleApps.  Any application that requires them, will not work.

Comment: So i tried again on a fresh install on a 4.2.2, I installed Gapps with ARM translation, Updated all my google apps however still my Clash of clans and facebook will not work.

Comment: I made a guess, based on the wildly inadequate info in your question.  Apparently it isn't correct.  Sorry.